# Does the existence of a free variable mean there are infinitely many solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

lets say I have an augmented matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2&0&3\\
0&1&0\\
2&1&3
\end{bmatrix}$$

The question is:
Is the matrix consistent with a unique solution, inconsistent, or consistent with an infinite solution?

row reducing gives:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&\frac32\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$

the answer given is: consistent, unique solution.

However, I thought if there is a free variable that indicates infinite solutions? Wouldn't the 3/2 be a free variable?

Comment: Are you working with augmented matrices or not?  Equivalently: Does the first row of the first matrix correspond to an equation like "$2x+0y=3$" or to an expression like "$2x+0y+3z$"?

Comment: You don't have a free variable

Comment: yes the question specifies it is an augmented matrix, does this mean 3/2 is not a variable? that would make sense, meaning it cant be free variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are considering an augmented matrix, the related system of equations is

- $2x=3$
- $y=0$
- $2x+y=3$

then the answer is correct, the *system is consistent and we have a unique solution*.

Comment: the question didn't specify specific equations it just gave the matrix

Comment: @Thomas If it is an augmented matrix then it corresponds to the system I given and then the solution is "the system is consistent and we have a unique solution".

Comment: The system is consistent, but it may be good to point out that that almost all three by three augmented systems like this have no solution if not considering least squares solutions.

Comment: @GavinRidley Yes indeed that's a very particular case.